How to fix NPM publishing error that wants to rename
I'm getting the following error when attempting to publish my npm package.
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/project-name- Package name too similar to existing package project-name; try renaming your package to '@user/package' and publishing with 'npm publish --access=public' instead
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or        
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.

I don't want to use @user/package. How do I fix this? Do I have to rename my github project as well? I couldn't find anything

Well this was a quick resolution.
In my package.json I changed the name and tried to publish again and it worked.
Before:
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.1",
}

After:
{
  "name": "my-project-js",
  "version": "1.0.1",
}

